# Android: Communication with host computer

Tags: android, ssh, serial-port, android-2.2-froyo, raspberry-pi

I am looking for ideas as to how all of you can think to solve this issue. I am going to be using an Android Tablet as basically a touch screen input for a project. I need to be able to control servos and solenoids and such, so I will be using a Raspberry Pi to do this. I am looking for ideas on how to get the tablet and the Raspberry Pi to talk. Here are a few that I have though of so far.

1. Use Wifi (which I really do not want to, Ethernet would be okay) to ssh into the Raspberry Pi (with an external library) and run scripts that way from the Android app.
2. Use a com port for Android (maybe Andropod if there hardware becomes available?) and run scripts on the Raspberry Pi.

Those are probably two of the "best" ideas that I can think of for now.

Can anyone think of any other "better" ideas?

Thanks in advance for the help,

Dan

Comment: What's the problem with using Wifi?

Comment: Have fun searching a Tablet with Ethernet port...

Comment: There isn't a huge issue with it, but I would rather not have to have a WiFi router and have to deal with security or channel interference of it. Also I have found some with Ethernet, but I would prefer to do a Nexus, which does not seem to have a way to get Ethernet.

Comment: You might have more luck on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for projects where people have already linked an Android device with a Raspberry Pi using WiFi and I came across this post. I can think of two "not too complex" methods of communicating.

One is to stick a WiFi dongle into the RPi and start a hotspot (on the RPi) for a direct connection from the Android device. The other is to use a Bluetooth dongle and communicate using a Bluetooth serial port. I have used the Bluetooth method communicating between an Android phone and an Arduino using a BlueSmIRf. (It is really handy for monitoring serial output on a roving device when you don't need a cable) It would be much cheaper since USB Bluetooth dongles are pretty cheap.

I would also assume that a direct connection with a USB cable might work. Maybe the phone might need to be in USB debugging mode the way it needs to be when using a tethering app like PDAnet. If fact, maybe tethering using PDAnet and a USB cable would do the job as well.

Personally, I am updating my RPi image right now to get the WiFi support added to the new Raspbian distribution.

Comment: Which post are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need more than what you are planning, if you touch the display nothing happens on the ssh or networking level, to do what you want to do you have to code an application as bridge between your input and your pc host that will do something specific for every kind of input that you want to check.

Also remember that in practice and in the vast majority of cases you do not have access to the vital part of Android, kernel modules included because is compiled as a monolithic one, so using the USB port it's not that easy and trivial, under Android the USB is just used to connect other devices that are managed by Android itself and not to build a 2 ways communication from a pc to the device and viceversa.

There is adb that is a telnet solution but requires developer settings enable on your device, also is subject to the level of rights that you have on your device.

The most realistic solutions are:

- you use an SSH server on the Android device an use it to communicate
- if this is not enough because you need to monitor the input and other stuff you will code your own app

the other solutions are:

- you root the phone
- you recompile the kernel as modular
- you write your own USB driver and load it into the new kernel
- you still have to code your own app for managing the user input ...

Comment: I am going to be coding my own app, so that is not the issue. My issue is finding the best way to communicate with the app. I have looked at some external ssh libraries that I would like to try and see if I could get those working. I do understand the issue with the USB and that is why I was thinking about the AndroPod, but was wondering if there was some other better way. I will probably not be recompiling the kernel. Thanks!

Comment: the most flexible solution is the one about using the network, the other solutions are really tricky and not even granted to work because you are supposed to do all the work and, as consequence, do the testing phase too. Use the network and you will be fine.

Comment: That is what I figured Ken, but I really do not like the WiFi idea,so I was trying to find an alternate solution.

Comment: @dannyn382 networking is not equal to using the wifi only, you can use whetever bus you like that has the drivers for delivering networking packages, it's a flexible solution.

Comment: Do you know of any other way to do this on the Android?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a web-app in the tablet and use [webiopi](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/wiki/README) to communicate with the raspberry-pi
But yeah this might not be a secure way to do things